# Horiontally Scrolling the List Item with buttons in React-Boostrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to make a horizontal list menu using react and react-boostrap. But as the length of the list gets bigger than container, the list gets out. I'm using overlow-Y as scroll there but I'd like to have 2 button through which I can scroll through the list. How can I do that in React? I want results like the one in picture.

...

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Jumbotron from "react-bootstrap/Jumbotron";
import ListGroup from "react-bootstrap/ListGroup";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [data, useData] = useState([
    { list: "appelllll" },
    { list: "ballllslsss" },
    { list: "cattsssssss" },
    { list: "dogssssss" },
    { list: "eggssss" },
    { list: "fatssssssssssssssssssss" },
    { list: "goatssssssssssssssss" },
    { list: "heloooooooooooooooooo" },
    { list: "ieloooooooooooooo" },
    { list: "jelooooooooo" },
    { list: "kelooooooo" },
    { list: "leooo" },
    { list: "melosdsadsado" }
  ]);

  return (
    <Container className="p-3">
      <ListGroup
        className="list_menu"
        horizontal
        style={{
          overflowX: "scroll"
        }}
      >
        <button>+</button>
        {data.map((data, i) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <ListGroup.Item
                className="list_item"
                key={i}
                onClick={() => console.log(data.list)}
              >
                {data.list}
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <button> > </button>
      </ListGroup>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```

...

[image]

my working demo is
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-rgb-koiwf?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Because you set

```
.list_menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}
```

So remove `width: 0;` in `.list_menu::-webkit-scrollbar` or remove `className="list_menu"` would work

```
<ListGroup
  className="list_menu"
  horizontal
  style={{
    overflowX: "scroll"
    }}
>
```

Comment: It use width: 0 to hide the bar coz I would like to move the bar with the buttons instead and not with the bar.